# Can a normal variable hold address of another variable?

Tags: c

My problem is quite crazy, but listen I created two normal variables just like this `int a,b` and then I assigned the address of `b` variable to the `a` and when I print the address of both `a` and `&b` it shows a random number but same for both.
How it is possible?
while `a` is not a pointer variable.

```
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    a = &b;
    printf("%u  %u",a,&b);
    return 0;
}

I got a number that must be address and both are same.
```

Comment: Doesn't compile in C++, seems to in C

Comment: You're code is ill. Pointers are used to store addresses. `int b, *a = &b;` . And `%p` should be used for printing pointer values.

Comment: The code contains a constraint violation (and as such any behaviour is undefined)

Comment: okay i know all the fact about pointer, plzz tell me why this code is working. and one thing it is working with c only not in cpp.

Comment: @Justin Turn on more warnings. A pointer on a 64-bit platform won't fit in a 32-bit `int`.

Comment: Your code does not compile without a `-fpermissive` in g++.

Comment: C doesn't care if the code will run correctly, it only cares if the syntax is correct, which it is. It will do exactly what you say without hesitation, regardless of consequences. Just because it compiles does not mean it's correct, useful, or without harmful side-effects. *It is your responsibility to write correct code, not the compiler to figure out what you mean.*

Comment: These are the warnings

||=== Build: Debug in crazy pointer (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Gaurav\Desktop\crazy pointer\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\Gaurav\Desktop\crazy pointer\main.c|7|warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|
C:\Users\Gaurav\Desktop\crazy pointer\main.c|8|warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]|
||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
||=== Run: Debug in crazy pointer (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|

Comment: @GauravKumar turn on `-Werror` as well

Comment: @tadman syntax is not enough. Semantics are required correct too. The semantics of this program are *wrong* but a C compiler is allowed to successfully compile an invalid program too.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala What I mean is the compiler doesn't care about semantics, it only cares about syntax *unless* you turn on more warnings to alert you about such things, or treat warnings as errors. Too many people presume that because something compiles it must be correct.

Answer (score 4):

1. If you compiled this program with a C compiler, the compiler is required to warn you that the types are wrong in `a = &b;`, because it violates the constraints for assignment. Did you get that warning? Did you ignore it?
2. After the compiler warned you, it presumably generated code for `a = &b;` to convert `&b`, which has type `int *`, to the type `int`. In some C implementations, an `int` can hold all the information of an `int *`, and the conversion works in a simple way. In some C implementations, an `int` is too small to hold all the information of an `int *`.
3. `printf("%u  %u",a,&b);` uses the wrong specifiers. `%u` is for an `unsigned int`, but `a` is an `int`, and `b` is an `int *`. The C standard does not define the resulting behavior when the wrong specifiers are used.
4. In spite of the lack of definition, quite likely, your C implementation printed the value of `a` as if it had been converted to an `unsigned int`, and it may have done the same with `&b`. This would result in the output of two identical numbers. This result is not reliable, due to the violation of the rules about specifiers mentioned above.
5. If your implementation does define the conversion of a pointer to an `int` in the common way and an `int` is wide enough to hold all the information of an `int *`, then a proper way to write your program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    a = (int) &b;
    printf("%#x %p\n", (unsigned) a, (void *) &b);
}
```

This is not guaranteed to show the same output strings for the two values, particularly because `%p` is flexible—the precise format is implementation-defined, so it may vary among C implementations. But they will be the same or similar in many C implementations.

Generally, pointers should not be converted to integers. However, there are times when this is necessary, as when writing kernel code that must deal with addresses in special ways or when writing high-performance code that must deal with alignment issues. In this situation, a better solution than using `int` is to include `<stdint.h>` and use `uintptr_t`. `uintptr_t` is an unsigned integer type that is suitable for converting to from pointers.

Comment: it is working with %d also and i get the warning that
warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]|

Comment: *"it presumably generated code to convert `&b`, which has type `int *`, to the type int"* - not really - the pointer value of `&b` will be passed as an argument (likely 32- or 64-bits on a modern system), and `printf` internally will use var-args techniques to read an `int`-sized (almost certainly 32-bits) argument from the stack memory where the function arguments will have been pushed: this is undefined behaviour but is *likely* to print the pointer value on 32-bit systems, or the top or bottom (depends on endianness) 32-bits of the pointer on 64-bit systems, without conversion code as such.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: That text in 2. refers to how the assignment expression operates. Typical compilers will, if they continue after diagnosing the constraint violation, process `a = &b;` by generating code that converts the address of `b` to an `int`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil oops :D indeed

Comment: @EricPostpischil: oh, fair enough.  Answer's unambiguous now it says `a = &b`.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

> Can a normal variable hold address of another variable?

Yes (maybe).

A compiler typically converts source code into machine code for the target CPU. For the CPU's machine code (for almost all CPUs) there are no types - everything (all instructions, all pointers, all integers, all floating point numbers, ...) are just patterns of bits; and the CPU has no idea if a pattern of bits (in memory or in a register) is an address or an integer or something else.

What this means is that if you can convince the compiler to store a pointer into an integer the CPU itself won't know or care.

For C; it's fairly easy to convince the compiler to store a pointer in an `int`, either by doing `a = &b;` and ignoring any warning; or by doing `a = (int)&b;` to suppress the warning. Of course this will not be portable, and the value may be mangled to fit (e.g. if a pointer is 64 bits and an `int` is 32-bits, then you can expect that half of the pointer will be discarded to make the value fit into the `int`).